# Should I use "IS or ARE there" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, differences

> "What ___ more on Earth grass or sand?"

Which sounds better?!

**A) is there;**

**B) are there.**

If you could explain why, I appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think one of them is not right?

Comment: It should be "...more of on Earth..."

Comment: Neither sentence would be grammatical as written.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to make this sentence work would be "what is there more of on Earth: grass or sand?", but as it doesn't seem to be an option, I'd choose "what is there more on Earth: grass or sand?". There are two reasons I'll to explain why this is. First, if you think about how you would answer this, then wouldn't you say: "there is more sand/grass (whichever is the answer) on Earth"? If that makes sense to you, which I hope it does, then I'll go on to the actual reason. The reason that you really should know is that "there is" will always be used with uncountable nouns, nouns that can't be given a numerical quantity such as sand, grass, corn, snow, glass, etc. (think about it, does it make sense for someone to say, "I have five sands"? Not really).